# Issue in Appending data using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

**Problem: -** I want to build a logic that take data like Attendance data, In Time, Employee Id and return a data frame with employee id, in time, attendance date and basically in which slot the employee entered. (Suppose In time is 9:30:00 of date 14-10-2019 so that if employee came at 9:30 so for that date and for that column it insert a value one.)

**Given Example below**

I tried lots of time to build logic for this problem but failed to build.

[image: dataset]

I have a dataset that looks like this.

I want an output like this so that whatever the time            (employee enter's) it only insert data to that time column only column only.:
[image: output]

This is my code but its only repeating last loop.

```
temp =[]
for date in nf['DaiGong']:
    for en in nf['EnNo']:
        for i in nf['DateTime']:


        col=['EnNo','Date','InTime','9:30-10:30','10:30-11:00','11:00-11:30','11:30-12:30','12:30-13:00','13:00-13:30']
        ndf=pd.DataFrame(columns=col)


        if i < '10:30:00' and i > '09:30:00':
            temp.append(1)
            ndf['9:30-10:30'] = temp
            ndf['InTime'] = i
            ndf['Date'] = date
            ndf['EnNo'] = en


        elif i < '11:00:00' and i > '10:30:00':
            temp.append(1)
            ndf['10:30-11:00'] = temp
            ndf['InTime'] = i
            ndf['Date'] = date
            ndf['EnNo'] = en
        elif i < '11:30:00' and i > '11:00:00':
            temp.append(1)
            ndf['11:00-11:30'] = temp
            ndf['InTime'] = i
            ndf['Date'] = date
            ndf['EnNo'] = en

        elif i < '12:30:00' and i > '11:30:00':
            temp.append(1)
            ndf['11:30-12:30'] = temp
            ndf['InTime'] = i
            ndf['Date'] = date
            ndf['EnNo'] = en

        elif i < '13:00:00' and i > '12:30:00':
            temp.append(1)
            ndf['12:30-13:00'] = temp
            ndf['InTime'] = i
            ndf['Date'] = date
            ndf['EnNo'] = en
        elif i < '13:30:00' and i > '13:00:00':
            temp.append(1)
            ndf['13:00-13:30'] = temp
            ndf['InTime'] = i
            ndf['Date'] = date
            ndf['EnNo'] = en
```

This is the output of my code.

[image: Output]

Comment: I haven't looked at your code but the output seems to be correct, right?

Comment: Sir , I want at whatever time any employee enters that should be add into that time slot column..  eg. If employee ID 4 enters between 9:30 to 10:30 , that count should be store in the column (date wise) . Please Help

Answer (score 0):

IIUC,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'EnNo':[2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3],
             'DaiGong':['2019-10-12', '2019-10-13', '2019-10-14', '2019-10-15', '2019-10-16', '2019-10-12', '2019-10-13', '2019-10-14', '2019-10-15'],
             'DateTime':['09:53:56', '10:53:56', '09:23:56', '11:53:56', '11:23:56', '10:33:56', '12:53:56', '12:23:56', '09:53:56']})

df
DaiGong DateTime    EnNo
0   2019-10-12  09:53:56    2
1   2019-10-13  10:53:56    2
2   2019-10-14  09:23:56    2
3   2019-10-15  11:53:56    2
4   2019-10-16  11:23:56    2
5   2019-10-12  10:33:56    3
6   2019-10-13  12:53:56    3
7   2019-10-14  12:23:56    3
8   2019-10-15  09:53:56    3

import datetime
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime']).dt.time #converting to datetime

def time_range(row): # I only wrote two conditions - add more
    i = row['DateTime']
    if i < datetime.time(10, 30, 0) and i > datetime.time(9, 30, 0):
        return '9:30-10:30'
    elif i < datetime.time(11, 0, 0) and i > datetime.time(10, 30, 0):
        return '10:30-11:00'
    else:
        return 'greater than 11:00'


df['time range'] = df.apply(time_range, axis=1)
df1 = pd.concat([df[['EnNo', 'DaiGong', 'DateTime']], pd.get_dummies(df['time range'])], axis=1)
df1
EnNo    DaiGong DateTime    10:30-11:00 9:30-10:30  greater than 11:00
0   2   2019-10-12  09:53:56    0   1   0
1   2   2019-10-13  10:53:56    1   0   0
2   2   2019-10-14  09:23:56    0   0   1
3   2   2019-10-15  11:53:56    0   0   1
4   2   2019-10-16  11:23:56    0   0   1
5   3   2019-10-12  10:33:56    1   0   0
6   3   2019-10-13  12:53:56    0   0   1
7   3   2019-10-14  12:23:56    0   0   1
8   3   2019-10-15  09:53:56    0   1   0

To get sum of count by employee,

df1.groupby(['EnNo'], as_index=False).sum()
```

Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Sir , I have total employee id 2 to 14 (eg. E Id.- 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14) . and I want that if any employee coming in 9:30-10:30  or so on other slots.. So I want to do just count that at each particular date at which time employee is entering . So insert there the count of total coming between the time... Sir I am new this , so please help .

Comment: @SauravMishra Update answer at end

Comment: Sir , I got this ... Thank you so much sir for giving me  your great time.

Answer (score 0):

My test data:

```
df:
    EnNo     DaiGong  DateTime
       2  2019-10-12  09:53:56
       2  2019-10-13  09:42:00
       2  2019-10-14  12:00:01
       1  2019-11-01  11:12:00
       1  2019-11-02  10:13:45
```

Create helper datas:

```
    tdr=pd.timedelta_range("09:00:00","12:30:00",freq="30T")

    s=pd.Series( len(tdr)*["-"] )
    s[0]=1

    cls=[ t.rsplit(":",maxsplit=1)[0] for t in tdr.astype(str) ]
    cols=[ t1+"-"+t2 for (t1,t2) in zip(cls,cls[1:]) ]
    cols.append(cls[-1]+"-")

tdr:
TimedeltaIndex(['09:00:00', '09:30:00', '10:00:00', '10:30:00', '11:00:00', '11:30:00', '12:00:00', '12:30:00'], dtype='timedelta64[ns]', freq='30T') 

cols:
 ['09:00-09:30', '09:30-10:00', '10:00-10:30', '10:30-11:00', '11:00-11:30', '11:30-12:00', '12:00-12:30', '12:30-'] 

s:
0    1
1    -
2    -
3    -
4    -
5    -
6    -
7    -
dtype: object
```

Use 'apply' and 'searchsorted' to get time slots:

```
df2= df.DateTime.apply(lambda t: \
         s.shift(tdr.searchsorted(t)-1,fill_value="-"))
df2.columns=cols

df2:
   09:00-09:30 09:30-10:00 10:00-10:30 10:30-11:00 11:00-11:30 11:30-12:00 12:00-12:30 12:30-
0           -           1           -           -           -           -           -      -
1           -           1           -           -           -           -           -      -
2           -           -           -           -           -           -           1      -
3           -           -           -           -           1           -           -      -
4           -           -           1           -           -           -           -      -
```

Finally, concatenate the two data frames:

```
df_rslt= pd.concat([df,df2],axis=1)

df_rslt:
    EnNo     DaiGong  DateTime 09:00-09:30 09:30-10:00 10:00-10:30 10:30-11:00 11:00-11:30 11:30-12:00 12:00-12:30 12:30-
0     2  2019-10-12  09:53:56           -           1           -           -           -           -           -      -
1     2  2019-10-13  09:42:00           -           1           -           -           -           -           -      -
2     2  2019-10-14  12:00:01           -           -           -           -           -           -           1      -
3     1  2019-11-01  11:12:00           -           -           -           -           1           -           -      -
4     1  2019-11-02  10:13:45           -           -           1           -           -           -           -      -
```